# LIKE clause and AND operator not working during DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to execute such command in mysql:

```
DELETE FROM product_description, product, product_to_store, url_alias WHERE
product_description.name LIKE '%|%' AND product.product_id = 
product_description.product_id AND product_to_store.product_id = 
product_description.product_id AND url_alias.query = 
CONCAT('product_id=',product_description.product_id)
```

However it gives me an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE product_description.name LIKE '%|%' AND product.product_id = product_descr' at line 1
```

When I will replace 'DELETE' with 'SELECT *' query works like a charm.

According to mysql doc

> Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same
>   table in a subquery.

So now I'm stuck with no idea how to perform such query, without using PHP

**EDITED**

My final query that worked:

```
DELETE product_description, product, product_to_store, url_alias 
FROM product_description, product, product_to_store, url_alias 
  WHERE product_description.name LIKE '%|%' AND product.product_id = 
  product_description.product_id AND product_to_store.product_id = 
  product_description.product_id AND url_alias.query = 
  CONCAT('product_id=',product_description.product_id)
```

So the tip was to add all 4 tables names just after DELETE to make it work, as JW wrote

Comment: Do you want to delete rows from 4 tables at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to specify on which the delete should takes place, in this example below, the records will be deleted in table `product_description`

```
DELETE product_description
FROM product_description, product, product_to_store, url_alias 
WHERE product_description.name LIKE '%|%' AND product.product_id = 
      product_description.product_id AND product_to_store.product_id = 
      product_description.product_id AND url_alias.query = 
      CONCAT('product_id=',product_description.product_id)
```

OR use `ANSI SQL-92` format

```
DELETE  product_description
FROM    product_description
        INNER JOIN product 
            ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id
        INNER JOIN product_to_store 
            ON product_to_store.product_id = product_description.product_id
        INNER JOIN url_alias 
            ON url_alias.query = CONCAT('product_id=',product_description.product_id)
WHERE   product_description.name LIKE '%|%'
```

Comment: he can also use `USING` **?**

Comment: Worked like a charm. Tjank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Delete syntax is:

```
DELETE FROM table_name [WHERE Clause]
```

you can't give multiple table_names in FROM clause (without JOIN, and USING clause).

```
DELETE table_name FROM table_name
INNER JOIN ....
```

or

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
USING table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
```

Reference: [**13.2.2. DELETE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//delete.html)
<sub>And Mr. JW already given you an answer</sub>

**USING example**

```
DELETE  
FROM    `product_description`, 
        `product`, 
        `product_to_store`, 
        `url_alias`

USING  `product_description`
        INNER JOIN `product` 
         ON `product`.`product_id` = `product_description`.`product_id`
        INNER JOIN `product_to_store` 
         ON `product_to_store`.`product_id` = `product_description`.`product_id`
        INNER JOIN `url_alias` 
         ON `url_alias`.`query` =
               CONCAT('product_id=',`product_description`.`product_id`)
WHERE   `product_description`.`name` LIKE '%|%'
```

**Side note:**  *Always use (`) for user defined identifiers.*